# Opennms customize text in event notifications

Tags: events, notifications, customization, opennms

In OpenNMS is it possible to add any of the "Asset data"  to event notification emails? For example  SNMP System Name, System Location, Contact, Description or 
Asset information Address, City, State, building, Floor, room, rack, etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can reference asset fields in the subject and body of your notification definitions in the form `%asset[address1]%`.

The SNMP `sysName`, `sysLocation`, `sysContact`, and `sysDescr` fields are not asset fields per se and cannot be accessed in this way.

Comment: Did my answer help at all?